# Channel shutdown: channel error: reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - reply consumer already set

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm running multiple tests with **spring-amqp**, **spring-rabbit**. My Maven parent is
**spring-boot-starter-parent:1.2.3.RELEASE** which pulls:

```
spring-rabbit:1.4.3.RELEASE
    spring-amqp:1.4.3.RELEASE
    amqp-client:3.4.2
```

At a certain point one of the tests fails with this error and I don't see the reason:

```
Executing callback on RabbitMQ Channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,2119)
Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - reply consumer already set, class-id=60, method-id=20)
Detected closed channel on exception.  Re-initializing: null
```

If I change to spring-boot-starter-parent:1.3.1.RELEASE all tests are passed.

Digging down in the different versions, it seems I can still reproduce the failed test with

```
spring-rabbit:1.5.0.M1
    spring-amqp:1.5.0.M1
    amqp-client:3.5.5
```

but all tests are passing with

```
spring-rabbit:1.5.0.RELEASE
    spring-amqp:1.5.0.RELEASE
    amqp-client:3.5.5
```

Is there any relevant change between 1.5.0.M1 and 1.5.0.RELEASE that could answer this?
I tried to browse [GitHub compare](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/compare/v1.5.0.M1...v1.5.0.RELEASE) but didn't help.

**1st update:**

I could narrow down the issue.
In the tests I **call sendAndReceive() to a queue inside a HystrixCommand** (from Netflix). This HystrixCommand uses a smaller (2s) timeout then the default reply timeout (5s) in RabbitTemplate.

A service is listening on that declared queue and returns the answer.

I have a certain test to **do a sendAndReceive() to a non-existing queue**.
When that special test is executed the HystrixCommand times out.

The next test executing sendAndReceive() to the declared queue gives the channel error.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringAmqpTestApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static final String QUEUE_NAME = "Spring-AMQP-Test";
    private static final String NONEXISTENT_QUEUE_NAME = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "@" + System.currentTimeMillis();

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        SpringApplication.run( SpringAmqpTestApplication.class, args );
    }

    @Autowired
    AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate;

    @Override
    public void run( String... args ) throws Exception {
        sendAndReceive( QUEUE_NAME );

        sendAndReceive( NONEXISTENT_QUEUE_NAME );

        sendAndReceive( QUEUE_NAME );
    }

    private void sendAndReceive( String routingKey ) {
        CustomHystrixCommand customHystrixCommand = new CustomHystrixCommand( amqpTemplate, routingKey );
        String answer = customHystrixCommand.execute();
        System.err.println( "< sendAndReceive(): " + answer );
    }
}
```

My HystrixCommand is fairly simple:

```
public class CustomHystrixCommand extends HystrixCommand<String> {

    private String routingKey;

    AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate;

    public CustomHystrixCommand( AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate, String routingKey ) {
        super( HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey( "" ), 2000 );
        this.amqpTemplate = amqpTemplate;
        this.routingKey = routingKey;
    }

    @Override
    protected String run() throws Exception {
        String request = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        MessageProperties messageProperties = new MessageProperties();
        Message message = new Message( request.getBytes(), messageProperties );
        Message answer = amqpTemplate.sendAndReceive( "", routingKey, message );
        return "OK answer";
    }

    @Override
    protected String getFallback() {
        return "getFallback()";
    }

}
```

With spring-boot-starter-parent:1.2.3.RELEASE my logs are:

```
< sendAndReceive(): OK answer
< sendAndReceive(): getFallback()
2016-01-27 11:47:42.266 ERROR 15007 --- [pool-1-thread-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - reply consumer already set, class-id=60, method-id=20)
< sendAndReceive(): getFallback()
```

while with spring-boot-starter-parent:1.3.1.RELEASE:

```
< sendAndReceive(): OK answer
< sendAndReceive(): getFallback()
< sendAndReceive(): OK answer
```

Thanks for any help / explanation.

Comment: Share that test, please. If you say that it isn't fixed in the `spring-amqp:1.4.3.RELEASE`, so we can play locally and reproduce. From other side not sure if it makes sense to fight, when you confirm that everything works well with 1.5 or later.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any changes (but haven't looked) but, in any case, 1.5.0.M1 is a pre-release `milestone` and 1.5.0.RELEASE is a release. Milestones should never be used when the actual release is available. The current release is 1.5.3.RELEASE.